# Loading Indicator is not working correctly

Tags: swift, uiactivityindicatorview

This is my code. I want to show an indicator when I click the button during passing data and adding data to database. How can I fix it?

```
@IBAction func addWishList(sender: AnyObject) {
     self.loading.startAnimating()
        addMovie(showMovie!) // Database add method.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
        let controller : WishListViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! WishListViewController

        if segue.identifier == "segue" {
            controller.user = self.tmpUser //  data from Facebook to pass another controller
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.loading.stopAnimating()
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addMovie` blocking main queue. You need to give some delay to add it to next run loop.
Try using:

```
@IBAction func addWishList(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.loading.startAnimating()
    //This will add to next main run loop.
    let dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) 
    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
            addMovie(showMovie!) // Database add method.

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do like following ..

```
   @IBAction func addWishList(sender: AnyObject) {

         self.loading.startAnimating()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

            addMovie(showMovie!) // Database add method.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.loading.stopAnimating()

    })
    })

}
```